# Checkbox click copy texblocks in to a string list

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

In the HierarchicalDataTemplate, i got 2 `textblocks`and I want to copy the texts from the both. During the check-box click/check it'll update the text to a list.

The function is getting the text from one textblock.

How can i get text from both textblocks and update it to the list?

```
private List<string> selectedNames = new List<string>();
private void TreeView_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    StackPanel stackPanel = chkBox.Parent as StackPanel;
    TextBlock txtBlock = FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(stackPanel);

    bool isChecked = chkBox.IsChecked.HasValue ? chkBox.IsChecked.Value : false;

    if (isChecked)
    {
        selectedNames.Add(txtBlock.Text );             
    }

}
```

CheckBox get text function:

```
private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
            return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

WPF HierarchicalDataTemplate:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
<CheckBox Name="checkBoxTree"  Checked="TreeView_Checked" Unchecked="checkBoxTree_Unchecked" 
          Margin="0,4,0,0"  Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<TextBlock >                               
           <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding XPath=@WebSite}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">  
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@WebSite}" /> 
           </Hyperlink>    
</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this at the moment, but I think that it *should* work:

```
private void TreeView_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    StackPanel stackPanel = chkBox.Parent as StackPanel;
    TextBlock txtBlock = FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(stackPanel);
    Hyperlink hyperlink = FindVisualChild<Hyperlink>(stackPanel);
    TextBlock secondTextBlock = FindVisualChild<TextBlock>(hyperlink);

    bool isChecked = chkBox.IsChecked.HasValue ? chkBox.IsChecked.Value : false;

    if (isChecked)
    {  
        selectedNames.Add(txtBlock.Text);   
        selectedNames.Add(secondTextBlock.Text);           
    }       
}
```

Let me know how it goes.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, so I wasn't sure whether that would work or not... it still looks like it *should* work, but I'll accept that you say it doesn't. So the only other way that I can think of you gaining access to that second `TextBlock` would be to give it a name and use the `FindName` method.

Rather than duplicate everything here, I'll point you towards the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN which features a detailed code example and explanation. In basic, you need to get the `ContentPresenter` from the relevant `TreeViewItem` and then you can access the `DataTemplate` from the `ContentPresenter`. Finally with the `DataTemplate`, you can access the `TextBlock` like this:

First change your XAML:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding XPath=@WebSite}" 
    RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">  
    <TextBlock Name="SecondTextBlock" Text="{Binding XPath=@WebSite}" /> 
</Hyperlink>
```

Then get hold of the `ContentPresenter` and use it like this:

```
TextBlock secondTextBlock = dataTemplate.
    FindName("SecondTextBlock", contentPresenter) as TextBlock;
if (secondTextBlock != null) selectedNames.Add(secondTextBlock.Text );
```

Comment: I'm getting null exception error when i apply the new hyperlink textblock at VisualTree.

Comment: Which object was `null`?

Comment: I understand 'the hyperlink' object was null. Among several nodes only some node of hyperlink has the value. for ex:`<Solution WebSite ="http://www.dnpphoto.eu/"/>`

Comment: @Shreidan: I tried your solution but still i'm getting blank fate from the Hyperlink text-block. I don't know what to do next?